# How do I add a contact form?

Tags: admin

I want to add my contact form on my wordpress but I don't know how to add new module? Can you please give me instruction?

Comment: what are you using to create your contact form? where do you want to add it?

Comment: Try the Contact Form 7 plugin if you're not a developer or want to save some time.

Comment: Contact form 7 and bootstrap for contact form 7 works really well together, add those plugins and you can use the form using short codes in your page or post check for the documentation " https://contactform7.com/docs/"

Answer (score 1):

There are many free and paid plugins you can activate to do this quickly and easily. [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), [Ninja Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/), and [Caldera Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/) are very popular but there are many more. Just go to the WP Dashboard Plugin > Add New > Search for Contact Forms > Install > Activate > Go to Plugin UI > Follow Plugin Directions. I used to use [custom written HTML form with a php script](https://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php) back in the day which can still work for WordPress site if you want to go ol skool.